# Fourier transform of a beat

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of a beat? For example, I want to calculate the Fourier transform of the function $$f(t)=\cos((\omega_p+\omega_v) t)+\cos((\omega_p-\omega_v)t),$$ where $\omega_p+\omega_v=\Omega,\space\omega_p-\omega_v=\omega$ and $\Omega\simeq\omega.$

I think it is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(\delta(\omega_p+\omega_v-\omega)+\delta(\omega_p-\omega_v-\omega)+\delta(\omega_v-\omega_p-\omega)+\delta(-\omega_p-\omega_v-\omega))$, is it right?

Comment: In case it's useful, $f(t) = 2 \cos(\omega_p t) \cos(\omega_v t)$.

Comment: I get: $\frac{1}{2}(\delta(\omega_p+\omega_v-\omega)+\delta(\omega_p-\omega_v-\omega)+\delta(\omega_v-\omega_p-\omega)+\delta(-\omega_p-\omega_v-\omega))$, is it right?

Comment: You may find it useful that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of the factors of the product.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I don't know how to use it in this case.